# How do I represent a utf8 hex character in a string literal?

Tags: swift

In the code below I'm trying to compare the first six bytes of some Data with a utf8 string literal which (in C) I could represent as `"\0x93NUMPY"`.  But that's not a valid way of representing a string literal in Swift.  So I've used the unicode character `u\0093`, which is two bytes long in utf8, and indexed the string data from 1..7, which works, but ...Yuk.

```
let magic = "\u{0093}NUMPY".data(using: .utf8)![1..<7]
guard  Data![0..<6] == magic else {
    return
}
```

How should I rewrite this code to avoid the confusing indexing issues, while still using a string literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not only confusing but also error-prone. It works for this particular byte because the UTF-8 representation of U+0093 happens to be `C2 93`. The same approach with U+00C0 would give the byte `0x80` because the UTF-8 representation is `C3 80`.

You could use the  *ISO Latin 1* encoding instead, which maps the Unicode code points `U+0000 .. U+00FF` to the bytes `0x00 .. 0xFF`:

```
let magic = "\u{0093}NUMPY".data(using: .isoLatin1)!
print(magic as NSData) // length = 6, bytes = 0x934e554d5059}
```

But actually I would not try to put arbitrary bytes into a string literal but define

```
let magic = Data([0x93]) + "NUMPY".utf8
```

instead. Note also that you can check the data for the prefix with

```
guard data.starts(with: magic) else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Your second improvement is what I was looking for.  I didn't realize that a string literal would get coerced through concatenation.

Comment: @JoshGreifer: `.utf8` returns the “UTF-8 view” of a string, which is a sequence of UInt8 bytes, and that is appended to the Data.